# Compute integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to Compute 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z $$
The Mathematica 9.01 give a result is $$-\frac{\pi}{24}+\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{3}+\log(7+4\sqrt{3})).$$ I want to know how to get it.

Comment: @user61527 Thanks, Now the problem is right.

Comment: this is lot easier if you know how to find a volume of a cube using spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I think its difficult for me. Can you write your answer? Please help me.

Comment: Integrating with respect to $z$ first, substitute $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\tan\theta$: $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dz=(x^2+y^2)\int_{0}^{\arctan{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}}\sec^3{\theta}\,d\theta$. This is interesting in its own right as an application of the famous secant-cubed integral.

Comment: @DavidH We know $\int \sec^3\theta\, d\theta= \frac{1}{2}(\sec \theta \tan\theta +\log|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|)+C$, but it is still difficult, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @DaoyiPeng Indeed, it is still quite a bit of complicated and tedious algebra, yet it is nevertheless helpful. Recalling standard [identities for compositions of trig functions with inverse trig functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions), the integral can eventually be ground down into the succinct form: $\frac12\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}+\coth^{-1}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2})}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following figure:

[image]

Due to symmetry one sixth of the rays emanating from $(0,0,0)$ leave the cube through the red triangle $T$. We therefore use the parametrization
$$\psi:\quad \left.\eqalign{x&=t\> u\cr y&=t\>v \cr z&=t\cr}\right\}\qquad(0\leq v\leq u, \ 0\leq u\leq 1, \ 0\leq t\leq 1)$$
with Jacobian $J_\psi=t^2$. It follows that the integral $(=:Q)$ in question is given by
$$Q=6\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^u t\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}\>t^2 dv\ du\ dt={3\over2}\int_0^1\int_0^u \sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}\  dv\ du\ .$$
Herewith the geometrical difficulties are out of the way and it remains to compute the nested integral using standard calculus techniques. A first step could be introducing polar coordinates
$$u=r\cos\phi, \quad v=r\sin\phi\qquad\left(0\leq r\leq{1\over\cos\phi},\quad 0\leq\phi\leq{\pi\over4}\right)\ ,$$
which leads to
$$Q={3\over2}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\cos\phi}r\>\sqrt{1+r^2}\ dr\ d\phi\ .$$
The inner integral is easy, and we are left with
$$Q={1\over2}\int_0^{\pi/4}\left((1+\cos^{-2}\phi)^{3/2}-1\right)\ d\phi\ ,$$
which has the quoted value $\ldots$

Comment: Maple produces $$ 3/2\,\int_{0}^{1}\!1/2\,\sqrt {2\,{u}^{2}+1}u+1/2\,{u}^{2}\ln  \left( 
\sqrt {2\,{u}^{2}+1}+u \right) -1/4\,\ln  \left( {u}^{2}+1 \right) {u}
^{2}+1/2\,\ln  \left( \sqrt {2\,{u}^{2}+1}+u \right) -1/4\,\ln 
 \left( {u}^{2}+1 \right) \,{\rm d}u
$$

Answer (score 3):

You are computing the average distance from a vertex in a unit hypercube. Assuming that $X,Y,Z$ are three independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$, and computing the probability density function of $W=X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ (that is a piecewise-simple function), it follows that

$$\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{W}] = \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\log(2+\sqrt{3})}{2}-\frac{\pi}{24}}=0.960591956455\ldots $$
As an alternative, you may just integrate $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ with respect to $x$ first, getting
$\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\frac{1}{2} \left(y^2+z^2\right) \log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$, then integrate the resulting expression with respect to $y$ and $z$. Lengthy but perfectly doable.